# By DataSet.Clear(), DataTable and DataColumn and DataRow are also removed?

Tags: c#, dataset

Suppose I have all of these in my code. These items are in the search section and the user may perform multiple searches and if the created objects are not deleted, there will be a problem.

```
        string myXMLfile =….;
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ds.ReadXml(myXMLfile);
        DataTable dt = ds.Tables["Table1"];
        DataTable tempdt = new DataTable();
        DataColumn Column = new DataColumn();
        Column.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String");
        Column.ColumnName = "Radif";
        tempdt.Columns.Add(Column);
        Column = new DataColumn();
        Column.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String");
        Column.ColumnName = "RootName";
        tempdt.Columns.Add(Column);
        …………
        ds.Clear();
```

Comment: No, it only [clears the row data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.dataset.clear?view=net-5.0).  The tables, and their columns, will still be there.

Comment: You could try or look it up on MSDN. Or dump it on other people :-(

Comment: To remove all [DataSet.Tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.data.dataset.relations) and then rows: [DataTableCollection.Clear Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.data.datatablecollection.clear). Also for example [DataRelationCollection.Clear Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.data.datarelationcollection.clear) for [DataSet.Relations](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.data.dataset.relations). To cleanup all things in one call: [DataSet.Reset Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.data.dataset.reset).

Answer (score 0):

No.

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestClear()
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ds.Tables.Add(new DataTable());
        ds.Tables[0].Columns.Add("Column", typeof(int));
        ds.Tables[0].Rows.Add(1);

        Assert.AreEqual(1, ds.Tables.Count);
        Assert.AreEqual(1, ds.Tables[0].Columns.Count);
        Assert.AreEqual(1, ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count);

        ds.Clear();

        Assert.AreEqual(0, ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count);
        Assert.AreEqual(1, ds.Tables[0].Columns.Count);
        Assert.AreEqual(1, ds.Tables.Count);
    }
```

Comment: Does ِds=null mean that that does not exist? With ds=null and dt=null and column=null, these object removed completely? I want the created objects to be removed at the end of the user's use.

Comment: Or they should not be destroyed even if they are created multiple times in a function؟